# Make a clone of an instanced with all the stored values

Tags: c#, deep-copy

I have two classes one called warehouse and one called Warehouselocations.
The wareHouse is currently able to create,store and find boxes in warehouselocation.

But now i also need the warehouse to be able to create a cloned version of wareHouseLocation with all the stored information.

```
   locations = new List<WareHouseLocation>();
```

This is the list where i store all the information. I want to be able to copy it.

I tried to find the answer my self and even tried some code but so far i had got nothing that works properly.

```
    public WareHouseLocation DeepCopy() 
    {
        foreach (WareHouseLocation  wareHouseLocation in locations)
            {
                if(wareHouseLocation == null) 
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else 
                {
                   //Need code here
                }
              }
           return null;
        }
```

The code is currently in the wareHouse class.
I be happy for anything that could help me.

```
    public class WareHouseLocation
    {
        public int FloorID { get; set; }
        public List<I3DStorageObject> storage = new List<I3DStorageObject>();


        public double MaxVolume;
        public double MaxWeight;

        public WareHouseLocation(double height, double width, double depth)
        {
            MaxVolume = height * width * depth;
            MaxWeight = 1000;
        }


        public bool hasAvailableVolumeForObject(I3DStorageObject s)
        {
            double currentVolume = 0;


            foreach (I3DStorageObject obj in storage)
            {
                currentVolume += obj.Volume;
            }

            double available = MaxVolume - currentVolume;


            if (s.Volume <= available)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }



    }
```

Here is the code for the WareHouseLocation.

Comment: Your return type is only good for 1 instance,  are  you going from a list to a singleton?

Comment: For a deep copy of the list (not the contained instances) `var newLocations = sourceInstance.locations.ToList();` ? Or are you looking for a deep copy of each instance in the list?

Comment: Even aside from that, we don't know what's in `WareHouseLocation` (which should *probably* be `WarehouseLocation` by the way, as "warehouse" is just one word). If you post the code for `WareHouseLocation`, we'll be able to help you work out how to clone one...

Comment: What is the `I3DStorageObject`, refence or value type?

Comment: `I3DStorage` is a reference typ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by implementing [`ICloneable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable?view=netframework-4.8) interface:

```cs
public class WareHouseLocation : ICloneable
{
    public int FloorID { get; set; }
    public List<I3DStorageObject> storage = new List<I3DStorageObject>();

    public double MaxVolume;
    public double MaxWeight;

    //rest of code

    public object Clone()
    {
        var copy = (WareHouseLocation)MemberwiseClone();
        copy.storage = storage.Select(item => (I3DStorageObject)item.Clone()).ToList();

        return copy;
    }
}
```

Since you have a `List` reference type inside `WareHouseLocation`, you'll need to properly clone this as well by implementing `ICloneable` for `I3DStorageObject` as well, because `MemberwiseClone` copy the reference only, not the referred object itself

```cs
public class I3DStorageObject : ICloneable
{
    public double Volume { get; set; }
    public object Clone()
    {
        return MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

You can also have a look at [`MemberwiseClone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=netframework-4.8) for details and examples of deep/shallow copy of objects

Comment: Thank you! I believe that exactly what i where looking for. i have been trying for hours to actually implementing a way to clone the object. But totally missed the `ICloneable` Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use JsonConvert.SerializeObject and JsonConvert.DeserializeObject for copy,

```
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(put_your_object_here);
    var copy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<your_object_type>(json);
```

Comment: That seems like a very inefficient way of performing a clone operation. We don't know what's in the `WareHouseLocation` class, but I suspect it would be pretty simple to clone directly.