# Changing an Object using a Copy is Still Causing the Source Object to Change

Tags: c#, copy

I have a point cloud object

```
public interface IPointCloud
{
    void ShiftToOrigin();

    Vertex[] Vertices { get; set; }

    // More here...
}

public class PointCloud : IEquatable<PointCloud>, IPointCloud
{
    public PointCloud()
    {
        Id = new TId();
    }

    public PointCloud(IPointCloud pointCloud) 
        : this(pointCloud.Vertices, pointCloud.Index, pointCloud.Source) { }

    public PointCloud(Vertex[] vertices) : this()
    {
        Vertices = vertices;
    }

    public PointCloud(Vertex[] vertices, int? index, string source = default)
        : this(vertices)
    {
        Index = index;
        Source = source;
    }

    #region Methods.
    public Vector3 GetCentroid()
    {
        var centroid = new Vector3();
        if (IsEmpty)
            return centroid;

        foreach (var vertex in Vertices)
            centroid += vertex.Point;

        return centroid / Vertices.Length;
    }

    public int ReorientateNormals()
    {
        if (!ContainsNormals)
            return 0;

        int counter = 0;
        var centroid = GetCentroid();
        for (int i = 0; i < Vertices.Length; ++i)
        {
            var normal = Vertices[i].Normal;
            Vertices[i].Normal = FlipNormalTowardCentroid(Vertices[i], centroid);

            if (normal != Vertices[i].Normal)
                counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    private Vector3 FlipNormalTowardCentroid(Vertex vertex, Vector3 centroid)
    {
        var normal = vertex.Normal.ToVector();
        var viewPointVector = (centroid - vertex.Point).ToVector();

        if (viewPointVector.DotProduct(normal) < 0)
            normal *= -1;

        return normal.ToVector3();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Translate point cloud so that center = origin total shift applied to this point cloud is stored in this->shift.
    /// </summary>
    public void ShiftToOrigin()
    {
        var (minimumBound, maximumBound) = GetBoundingBoxAsPoints();
        Vector3 newshift = Vector3.Divide(minimumBound + maximumBound, 2.0f);

        for (int i = 0; i < Vertices.Length; ++i)
            Vertices[i].Point = Vertices[i].Point - newshift;

        GlobalShiftVector += newshift;
    }

    public virtual void RemovePoints(IPointCloud pointCloudToRemove)
    {
        if (pointCloudToRemove.Vertices == null || pointCloudToRemove.Vertices.Length == 0)
            return;

        var verticesToKeep = new List<Vertex>();
        var verticesToRemove = pointCloudToRemove.Vertices.ToList();

        foreach(var vertex in Vertices)
        {
            if (!verticesToRemove.Contains(vertex))
                verticesToKeep.Add(vertex);
        }
        Debug.Assert(verticesToKeep.Count == Vertices.Length - verticesToRemove.Count);

        Array.Clear(Vertices, 0, Vertices.Length);
        Vertices = verticesToKeep.ToArray();
    }

    public IPointCloud Merge(IPointCloud pointCloud)
    {
        if (pointCloud == null || pointCloud.Vertices.Length == 0)
            return this;

        List<Vertex> vertices = pointCloud.Vertices.ToList();
        if (Vertices == null || Vertices.Length == 0)
            return new PointCloud(vertices.ToArray(), pointCloud.Index, pointCloud.Source);

        vertices.AddRange(Vertices);
        return new PointCloud(vertices.ToArray(), Index, Source);
    }

    public (Vector3 MinimumBound, Vector3 MaximumBound) GetBoundingBoxAsPoints()
    {
        var min = new Vector3();
        var max = new Vector3();

        if (Vertices.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var point in Vertices.Select(v => v.Point))
            {
                if (min.X > point.X)
                    min.X = point.X;

                if (min.Y > point.Y)
                    min.Y = point.Y;

                if (min.Z > point.Z)
                    min.Z = point.Z;

                if (max.X < point.X)
                    max.X = point.X;

                if (max.Y < point.Y)
                    max.Y = point.Y;

                if (max.Z < point.Z)
                    max.Z = point.Z;
            }
        }
        return (min, max);
    }

    public BoundingBox GetBoundingBox()
    {
        var (MinimumBound, MaximumBound) = GetBoundingBoxAsPoints();
        return new BoundingBox(
            new Range(MinimumBound.X, MaximumBound.X),
            new Range(MinimumBound.Y, MaximumBound.Y),
            new Range(MinimumBound.Z, MaximumBound.Z));
    }

    public double GetPointDensity()
    {
        var boundingBox = GetBoundingBox();
        var volume = boundingBox.XRange.Length * boundingBox.YRange.Length * boundingBox.ZRange.Length;
        return Vertices.Length / volume;
    }
    #endregion // Methods.

    #region Operator Overrides.
    public bool Equals([AllowNull] PointCloud other)
    {
        return other.Id == Id;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(PointCloud left, PointCloud right)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, null))
            return ReferenceEquals(right, null);

        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(PointCloud left, PointCloud right)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, null))
            return !ReferenceEquals(right, null);

        return !left.Equals(right);
    }
    #endregion // Operator Overrides.

    #region Object Overrides.
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the specified <see cref="Range"/> is equal to the current one.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The <see cref="Range"/> object to compare with the current one.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if the specified <see cref="Range"/> is equal to the current one;
    /// otherwise <c>false</c>.</returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj as PointCloud);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serves as a hash function for a particular type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A hash code for the current <see cref="Range"/>.</returns>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 29 + Id.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder($"Point Cloud {{{Id}}}, Index {Index ?? -1:N0} (\"{Source}\"), ");
        builder.Append($"\tVertex count {Vertices.Length:N0}, Contains Normals = {ContainsNormals.ToString()}");
        return builder.ToString();
    }
    #endregion // Object Overrides.

    public TId Id { get; private set; }

    public Vertex[] Vertices { get; set; }

    public int? Index { get; set; }

    public string Source { get; set; }

    public bool IsEmpty => Vertices == null || Vertices.Length == 0;

    public bool ContainsNormals => Vertices == null ? false : Vertices.Any(v => v.Normal.X != 0.0f || v.Normal.Y != 0.0f || v.Normal.Z != 0.0f);

    public Vector3 GlobalShiftVector { get; private set; }
}
```

where

```
public class Vertex : IEquatable<Vertex>, ICloneable
{
    public Vertex() { }
    public Vertex(Vector3 point, Vector3 normal)
    {
        Point = point;
        Normal = normal;
    }
    public Vertex(Vector3 point) : this(point, new Vector3()) { }

    #region IClonable.
    public object Clone()
    {
        return (Vertex)MemberwiseClone();
    }
    #endregion // IClonable.

    #region Object Overrides.
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj as Vertex);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 29 + Point.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 29 + Normal.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
    #endregion //  Object Overrides.

    #region Comparison Operators.
    public static bool operator ==(Vertex left, Vertex right)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, null))
            return ReferenceEquals(right, null);

        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Vertex left, Vertex right)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, null))
            return !ReferenceEquals(right, null);

        return !left.Equals(right);
    }
    #endregion // Comparison Operators.

    #region IEquatable<Vertex>.
    public bool Equals(Vertex other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(other, this))
            return true;

        return Point.IsEqual(other.Point) &&
               Normal.IsEqual(other.Normal);
    }
    #endregion // IEquatable<Vertex>.

    public Vector3 Point;

    public Vector3 Normal;
}
```

On this object I wish to perform some calculations but *I do not want to modify the original*. So, in the method below

```
public List<LineDescriptor> HoughTansform(IPointCloud pointCloud)
{
    _dX = _settingsProvider.LfdSolverSettings.HoughSpaceStepSize.Value;
    _minimumVotes = _settingsProvider.LfdSolverSettings.HoughMinimumVotesForLineSelection.Value;

    if (pointCloud.Vertices.Length < 2)
        throw new PointCloudException("Point cloud has less than two points");

    // Add more checks once we expose for parameterization. 
    if (_dX < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("dX cannot be negative");

    if (_minimumVotes < 2)
        _minimumVotes = 2;

    // Ensure we get a shallow copy. 
    var basePointCloud = new PointCloud(pointCloud.Vertices.Select(v => (Vertex)v.Clone()).ToArray());
    
    var (minimumBound, maximumBound) = basePointCloud.GetBoundingBoxAsPoints();
    double d = (maximumBound - minimumBound).Norm();

    if (d == 0.0)
        throw new PointCloudException("All points in point cloud are identical");

    // ... More stuff here
```

I am attempting to create a new copy using the array of `Vertex` so that I am not modifying the original point cloud object `pointCloud`. I first tried using the simple

```
var basePointCloud = new PointCloud(pointCloud.Vertices);
```

But this was still modifying the original for some reason. Following the advice below, I then updated this, to use the following "shallow copy method"

```
    var basePointCloud = new PointCloud(pointCloud.Vertices.Select(v => (Vertex)v.Clone()).ToArray());
```

this works fine when the debugger is attached, but amazingly it does not work when run in release mode, the the bounding box gets calculated so that d = 0.0 - something about this is nasty.

**How can I ensure I make a proper clean copy so that my changes to `basePointCloud` do not effect the original `pointCloud` object?**

Note, I cannot create a deep copy using any form of serialization as due to the use of the `Vector3` struct, my `IPointCloud` objects are not serializable.

**UPDATE**

It is actually

```
var (minimumBound, maximumBound) = basePointCloud.GetBoundingBoxAsPoints();
```

this line, why is returning a tuple of `(0.0f, 0.0f)`? I have used some `Console.WriteLine`s to see what is going on

- [in `basePointCloud.GetBoundingBoxAsPoints`] Vertices.Length = 206
- [in `basePointCloud.GetBoundingBoxAsPoints`] min = <-147.247, -109.066, 0>, max = <132.522, 167.362, 1470.4>
- [`var (minimumBound, maximumBound)` = ] min = <0, 0, 0>, max = <0, 0, 0>
- d = 0

The return and setting of the tuple fails. I have tried using

```
(Vector3 minimumBound, Vector3 maximumBound) = basePointCloud.GetBoundingBoxAsPoints();
```

but this also give the above result. I am confused.

Comment: There is no need to call `pointCloud.Vertices.ToList().ToArray()`, you can just use `ToArray()`. And you still use a copy of items in `Vertices`

Comment: This is me playing about - neither of these work.

Comment: you can create a new instance manually, or implement `ICloneable` for `Vertex`. However, it's not recommended

Comment: The very similar question [Make a clone of an instanced with all the stored values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59443929/make-a-clone-of-an-instanced-with-all-the-stored-values)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski you'd recomend going down the struct route for the `Vertex` class?

Comment: Switching `Vertex` to immutable struct seems to be a good option, as suggested in the answer below. Otherwise you should implement `ICloneable` and use `MemberwiseClone` all the way. `Vertex` also should implement it

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This was stupidly due to editing the variable of the immutable struct `Vector3`. Very poor. :'[

Answer (score 3):

`Vertex` is a reference type. Making a copy of a `Vertex` array doesn't make a copy of the items contained within. Both the original array and the copy will hold references to same `Vertex` objects.

One solution is converting `Vertex` to a value type. Looking at the class definition, its doesn't seem to be a bad choice if making it immutable is an option. Mutable structs is always a bad idea.

Another possible option (yuck!) is making a copy mechanism in `Vertex` that returns a copy, and then project that to a new array:

```
new PointCloud(pointCloud.Vertices.Select(v => v.Copy()).ToArray());
```

But I'd recommend the first option if possible. If you need copy by value semantics, then use the tools the type system provides; value types.

Comment: Adding the method `public Vertex Copy()
  {
   return new Vertex(Point, Normal);
  }` and doing as you suggest also dos not work. Or will I have to go further and copy component wise for the vector (that is X, Y, and Z).

Comment: It seems it has to be done via `IClonable`, `public object Clone()
  {
   return (Vertex)MemberwiseClone();
  }`

Comment: @MoonKnight That doesn't make much sense. If `Vertex`'s inner state is only made up of value types then the copy should work. Are you showing all the members of Vertex?

Comment: Yes, they are the only two members and they are both of type `struct Vector3`. The clone worked, the "copy" did not.